# Kohana date warning message

Tags: php, database, kohana

My site admin panel coded via Kohana. And when click Corporate->Add New, have a problem:

```
An error was detected which prevented the loading of this page. If this problem persists, please contact the website administrator.

panel/application/controllers/admin/corporate/news.php [82]:

date() [function.date]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Europe/Helsinki' for 'EEST/3.0/DST' instead
```

And Stack Trace:

```
panel/application/controllers/admin/corporate/news.php [82]:

date( Y-m-d, 1336401401 )

News_Controller->add(  )
```

82.line:

```
$dbForm->date->value = date('Y-m-d',time());
```

Whats problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In your bootstrap.php, have you commented out your set default timezone line (line 25 in the 3.2.0 default install):

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
```

That is what it is complaining about.

Comment: But im using Kohana 2 version and not found date function in bootstrap.php

Comment: Add it.  It's a PHP function and will likely solve your issue.